# Save figure with centered plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save the figure with an Y axis title and ticks, but keeping the frame of the graph horizontally centered.

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png')
```

While the displayed figure in my Jupyter Notebook is centered:
[image]

The file `/tmp/test.png` is not:

[image]

I'd like it to be the same space between the black vertical bar in the left with the left edge of the image, and the black vertical bar in the right with the right edge of the image.

Comment: Which horizontal bars? The two horizontal bars I see are the lower and upper x-axis, and those are not just at the right edge.

Comment: Looking  at the images individually, by opening them in a separate tab, shows the extra whitespace. It's definitely not clear on StackOverflow with a white background (for me, the two y-axes of the two images even align perfectly, so nothing seems off-center for me).

Comment: See if using `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.savefig` helps.

Comment: You can do this manually to ensure you have a centred subplot. 1st, make sure you are **not** using `tight_layout` or `constrained_layout` when you save. 2nd, use `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9)` (adjust those numbers if needed, but make sure `1-right = left` to keep the plot centred.

Comment: This works but in the saved image it is ignored, it seems to automatically apply tight_layout before saving

Comment: check your `rcParams` or your `.matplotlibrc` configuration file for a setting applying tight_layout to saved plots: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html. For example, you probably want `figure.autolayout` and `figure.constrained_layout.use` to be `False`

Comment: Tried modifying the rcParams but the image saved is still fitted

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. Update matplotlib. preferable `conda update --all` in (base), and if appropriate, activate the relevant environment and also do `conda update --all`. Additionally, if you are not, then you should be using `jupyter lab` not `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Using matplotlib 3.8.1 in jupyter lab. The problem is with the image saved, not with jupyter lab.